# Terser: Annotate function as always pure (and what does it mean)

Tags: javascript, pure-function, terser

To assist with optimization Terser supports the pure comment to indicate that a function call is pure.  Specifically, the [docs](https://terser.org/docs/api-reference) give only the following example.

```
const x = /*#__PURE__*/i_am_dropped_if_x_is_not_used()
```

But, usually, if I define a pure function every use of it is pure.  Is there a way to use comments to indicate that the function is always pure?  If not do I have to manually list out the functions and pass them into the pure_funcs option?

--

Also, does the pure annotation really require that that the function be pure in a mathematical/functional programming sense, or is it enough that it be idempotent?  For instance, if the function getModel(id) keeps a cache behind the scenes to improve performance will it cause problems if I mark it as pure?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this in your config:

```js
new TerserPlugin({
  terserOptions: {
    compress: {
      pure_funcs: [
        '<yourFunction>',
      ],
    },
  },
}),
```

You can find documentation in compress options [here](https://terser.org/docs/api-reference#compress-options).